# Entity Framework: updated record being inserted (instead of updated)

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, updating

I'm using the following code to UPDATE certain records from the db:

```
        IList<Item> list;
        using (DbContext context = new DbContext()
        {
            list = Item.ToList();
            foreach (Item item in list)
            {
                // attach the item
                context.Item.Attach(item);

                item.Updated = DateTime.Now; 
                context.Items.Add(item);
                context.SaveChanges();
             }
        }
```

The problem is that EF is INSERTING a new item instead of updating the updated item... I've searched abit on the site and saw a suggestion to attach the item to the DbContext, but thats not working either? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I've made a little change to my answer: It is usually better to call `SaveChanges` only once after the `foreach` loop, not inside of the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The procedure should be:

```
using (DbContext context = new DbContext()
{
    foreach (Item item in list)
    {
        item.Updated = DateTime.Now; 
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;//attaches automatically
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You are calling `Add` which means INSERT.